# Como abrir um article em nova pagina com um tamanho que não ocupe 100%?

Tags: html, css, html5

Meu `article` está sendo exibido em uma chamada na página index, gostaria que ele abrisse em uma nova pagina mas com uma largura que não seja 100%.

```
       <article id="tres" class="caixa caixa2 sombra">
            <img src="noticia01.jpg" alt="" title="">
            <h2 class="titulo vermelho">ted</h2>
            <p>noticia 1 ...</p>
            <a href="noticias.html" class="botao botao-medio botao-vermelho bordas">botao 1</a>
        </article>

        <article class="caixa caixa2 sombra bordas">
            <img src="noticia02.jpg" alt="" title="">
            <h2 class="titulo rosa">ted1</h2>
            <p>noticia 02</p>
            <a href="noticias.html" class="botao botao-medio botao-amarelo bordas">botao 2</a>
        </article>

        <article class="caixa caixa2 sombra bordas">
            <img src="noticia03.jpg" alt="" title="">
            <h2 class="titulo azul">ted2</h2>
            <p>noticia 03</p>
            <a href="noticias.html" class="botao botao-medio botao-azul bordas">botao 3</a>
        </article>
```

Comment: Quando vc diz nova página, vc quer dizer oq? Que seja redirecionado para essa nova página, que seja mostrado em um modal-box ou que abra uma nova guia/aba no navegador?

Comment: @LipESprY em uma nova guia do navegador .
é possivel ?

Comment: É sim. Basta adicionar a tag `target` com valor `_blank` nos seus links: `<a href="noticias.html" target="_blank" class="botao botao-medio botao-vermelho bordas">botao 1</a>`

Comment: @LipESprY  mais desta forma ela vai abrir em outra pagina mais com ma largura 100% ne ?

Comment: só falta  essa pequena parte .
a noticia abrir numa largura definida por min

Comment: Ora, agora basta vc estilizar essa página conforme sua vontade... É uma página *HTML* como qualquer outra...

Comment: tendi muito obrigado

Comment: @LipESprY eu estilizei a minha pagina chamada noticias.html conforme quero que a noticia aparece. mais ao clicar na pagina index.html pelo link direto. os artigos que contem a noticia fica sobrepondo umas das outras...
eu queria fazer com que ao clicar na pagina eventos.html aparecicem os artigos pequenos um abaixo do outro. e ao clicar em algum deles ,eles abrissem.
entendeu ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi. Seu objetivo seria uma página com uma lista das notícias (pequenas) e uma página para cada notícia (completa)?

Comment: @LipESprY e tipo isso

Comment: como eu vejo em muitos sites

Comment: @LipESprY possivel fazer isso ?

Comment: Basta vc criar sua páginas HTML, como mencionei. A forma simples é vc criar um arquivo para cada notícia e "*linkar*" na sua página principal que mostra todas as notícias...